# Determining the caller inside a setter -- or setting properties, silently

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged, c#-5.0

Given a standard view model implementation, when a property changes, is there any way to determine the originator of the change?  In other words, in the following view model, I would like the "sender" argument of the "PropertyChanged" event to be the actual object that called the `Prop1` setter:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double Prop1
    {
        get { return _prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (_prop1 == value)
                return;
            _prop1 = value;

            // here, can I determine the sender?
            RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName: "Prop1", sender: this);
        }
    }
    private double _prop1;

    // TODO implement INotifyPropertyChanged
}
```

Alternatively, is it possible to apply `CallerMemberNameAttribute` to a property setter?

Comment: The `sender` parameter of the PropertyChanged event must always be `this`.  Otherwise you would break the usage of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.  Notice that `PropertyChangedEventArgs` only contains a property name and not which instance that belongs to.  The instance that the property belongs to must be the sender.   If you don't pass `this` the code that tries to access the property by name will throw an exception.

Comment: @shf301 I can see that `sender` would logically be the instance that owns the event ... but that is not in any way *required*, is it?  Or are you saying that WPF/Silverlight bindings use the `sender` parameter to retrieve the updated value?

Comment: How else would the consumer of the `NotifyPropertyChanged` event know which object raised the event?  What if an object registers to `NotifyPropertyChanged` on two different objects?

Comment: @shf301 it's an interesting point, so I tested it -- it seems that a WPF binding still works if the `sender` is some other object.  Presumably the subscribing object/binding holds a reference to the source object, and doesn't rely on `sender`.

Comment: "but that is not in any way required, is it?" Unless you know every single subscriber to your class, you should assume that somewhere, one might rely on `INotifyPropertyChanged` being implemented as documented. It's not that I *expect* your idea to break, but if it does, the blame lies solely with you, and there is a real possibility that it *could* break on, say, the not yet existing .NET 5, third-party controls, property forwarders, plenty of other helper classes that all hook into `PropertyChanged`.

Comment: Have you considered using commands instead? In a command you can pass in a parameter. What MVVM framework are you using? I have used MVVM light in the past and was able to do something similar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're asking about the caller of the setter. That means, the previous method call in the call stack before getting to the setter itself (which is a method too).

Use `StackTrace.GetFrames` method for this. For example (taken from http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/):

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[STAThread]
public static void Main()
{
  StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();           // get call stack
  StackFrame[] stackFrames = stackTrace.GetFrames();  // get method calls (frames)

  // write call stack method names
  foreach (StackFrame stackFrame in stackFrames)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name);   // write method name
  }
}
```

The output:

```
Main
nExecuteAssembly
ExecuteAssembly
RunUsersAssembly
ThreadStart_Context
Run
ThreadStart
```

Basically, what you're asking for would be `stackFrames[1].GetMethod().Name`.

Comment: Great, this is what I asked for.  Using `stackFrames[1].GetMethod().Type` gets the type of the class that called the setter.  Thanks!

Comment: be aware the `StackTrace` object is fairly useless in release builds with optimised code and no debug info. Check your release build, the info may not be there.

Answer (score 5):

My first approach to your problem would be to derive from `PropertyEventArgs`. The new class would have a member called, for instance `PropertyChangeOrigin` in addition to `PropertyName`. When you invoke the `RaisePropertyChanged`, you supply an instance of the new class with the `PropertyChangeOrigin` set from the information gleaned from the `CallerMemberName` attribute. Now, when you subscribe to the event, the subscriber could try casting the `eventargs` to your new class and use the information if the cast is successful.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I always use as a middle-ground between `INotifyPropertyChanged` and my View Models:

```
public class NotifyOnPropertyChanged : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IDictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs> _arguments;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
    {
        if(_arguments == null)
        {
            _arguments = new Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
        }

        if(!_arguments.ContainsKey(property))
        {
            _arguments.Add(property, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }

        PropertyChanged(this, _arguments[property]);
    }
}
```

Two things here. It uses the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute to set the property name. This makes the usage syntax as follows:

```
public string Words
{
    set
    {
        if(value != _words)
        {
            _words = value;
            OnPropertyChanged( );
        }
    }
}
```

Beyond that, it stores the `PropertyChangedEventArgs` object in a dictionary so it's not created a ton of times for properties that are frequently set. I believe this addresses your problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have had to pass in extra information down into a VM I have a great success with using commands:

[Commands, RelayCommands and EventToCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)